# How do I detect an internet connection and then add an anchor (link) to an element, such as a div, or not add it if there is no connection

Tags: javascript

I am developing a basic HTML app for ipad. It will be used offline, but when it is online, I want an element on the page to have a link attached to it. I am a complete newb to javascript, so any help will be appreciated.

I have managed to add the link to the element when online, but when offline, it is still there. What do I have wrong here?

```js
var isOnline = window.navigator.onLine; 
var a = document.getElementById('webviewBtn');
if (isOnline) {  
  
 a.setAttribute("href", "http://pixelwizard.com.au");
} else {
  
 a.setAttribute("href", "#");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an `<a>` element to be a link, don't give it an `href`. You're setting its `href` to `"#"` if the device is offline, which makes it appear as a clickable link.